# Deleting character from a string

Tags: java, string

I have a String which i am entering through console.

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = obj.next();
```

Now i want to delete specific character from that string and that character is also being entered from console.

```
System.out.println("Enter the character which you want to delete from your string");
String s1=obj.next();
```

Please explain how we can do this??

Comment: [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: Are you planning on deleting a single character or all occurences? `String.replace()` and `replaceAll()` should help you (you can replace matches with the empty String)

Comment: all its occurrences.

Comment: `s.replaceAll(s1, "")` will replace all occurrences of `s1` in string `s`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the character, replace it with nothing.

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = obj.next();
System.out.println("Enter a character to delete");
char ch = (char)System.in.read();
s = s.replace(ch + "", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert that string to char array 



  String s = obj.next();
    Char[] arrstr = s.toCharArray()
```

Create a string buffer

```
StringBuffer newstring= new StringBuffer("");

Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String chartoreplace = obj.next();
```

iterate over that array and store characters that you dont want to replace in buffer

```
for(Char ch : arrstr){
    if(!ch.equals(chartoreplace)
    {
    newstring.append(ch);
    }
    }
```

at the end return string stored in the buffer as

```
     newstring.toString();
```

Other way to replace

```
String s = obj.next();
  System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String chartoreplace = obj.next();
s.replace('chartoreplace ','');
```

this will replace that character

Comment: plus one for using this condition if(!ch.equals(chartoreplace). Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Uma Kanth but to make it more correct. You can't modify a string because it is immutable. You are generating a new object and your string variable references to it. But Uma Kanth ist right

Answer (score 0):

So use `s.replaceAll(s1,"")`//to replace all occurrences of given string.

use `s.replace(s1,"")`//replace only once

```
s=s.replaceAll(s1,"");
System.out.println(s);
```